# Do I have to free structs created with Cgo?

Tags: go, cgo

I create C structs in my Go code, like this:

```
var data C.MyStruct_t
```

Do I have to free them manually at some point, like I do when I use CString? With CString I often do something like:

```
ctitle := C.String(title)
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(&ctitle))
C.my_func(&ctitle)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You only call `free` on something that was allocated via the C `*alloc` functions. The `C.CString` and `C.CBytes` functions are documented as doing so internally, and requiring the use of `C.free`.

In this case even though `data` is of type `C.MyStruct_t` it is allocated in Go, and therefor will be handled by the Go garbage collector.